# An inequality for the trace of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix. Are there any simple conditions under which

$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^T A) \geq \operatorname{Tr}(A)^2 $$

or vice versa?

I do know the following: if $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_j \geq 0$, then

$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^T A)  = \sum \lambda_j^2 \leq  (\sum \lambda_j)^2  =  \operatorname{Tr}(A)^2 .$$

The same is true if $A$ has only negative eigenvalues. I am looking for more general circumstances under which we have inequality one way or the other.

Comment: Do you care about the underlying field? Are you working in $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: This is over $\mathbb R$; over a different field (one which is not linearly ordered) the $\geq$ sign would not make sense.

Comment: $\text{Tr}(A^2) = \sum \lambda_j^2$, but that's not the same in general as $\text{Tr}(A^T A)$.  Of course it would be the same if $A$ was symmetric.

Comment: For example, try $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$: eigenvalues are $0$, $\text{Tr}(A^T A) = 1 > 0 = \text{Tr}(A)^2$.

Comment: [The example was wrong]

Comment: No, $\text{Tr}(A^T A) = +2$ in that case.  $\text{Tr}(A^T A) = \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}^2 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you're working over the real numbers.
Your inequality is true for matrices of rank $1$.  In fact if $A = u v^T$ for column vectors $u$ and $v$, $\text{Tr}(A^T A) = (u^T u)(v^T v)$ while $\text{Tr}(A)^2 = (u^T v)^2$, and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says $(u^T v)^2 \le (u^T u)(v^T v)$.

Comment: What about a matrix of the form $A+B$, where $A$ is rank 1 and $B$ is positive definite symmetric?

Comment: For symmetric positive definite $B$ the inequality goes the other way.